# LibGDX live wallpaper not displaying textures

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I am working on making a live wallpaper . Initially I started out by making the desktop version

[image: desktop version]

I then followed this [tutorial](http://molotuspi.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-make-simple-android-live.html)  to turn into an android livewallpaper .

after that when I am running this on my device (Nexus 7 2012 version rooted ) this is what I get

[image]

I am at my wits end. Where should I be looking?

EDIT : I ran this on my Motorola E 4.4.4 . It is working like silk . Now I am more confused

:(

Some details

The loading code

```
public static void load(){
        clownfishtexture = new Texture("left.png");
        clownfishRegion = TextureRegion.split(clownfishtexture, 144, 84)[0];
        background = new Texture("aquarium.png");
        backgroundRegion = new TextureRegion(background, 0, 0, 480, 854);
}
```

The clownfish texture is a 32 bit png with dimensions of 2860 * 84 
I then split it into regions .

Comment: Are you using a custom shader? Maybe it's not compiling. Desktop GLSL can be more forgiving of syntax in a shader, and doesn't require that you specify float precision in the fragment shader.

Comment: I am very new to openGL , no custom shaders . It is just a texture with 20 frames.

Comment: It could also be the format of your image or how you're loading it. Show your code for loading the texture(s) and tell us what format the image is in (jpg, 24bit png, 32bit png?)

Comment: I have updated with the code and image details.

Comment: Not all devices support textures with any dimension greater than 2048. That's most likely the problem.